# Grafico em linha php

Tags: php

Estou tentando monta gráfico em linha mas estou tendo problema no

> mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Esse erro me aparece, se puderem me ajuda a ter um aluz agradeço. segue codigo:

```
<?
include"conexao.php"; 
$seleciona_artigos = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  artigo order by artigo_visual desc " );
$seleciona_total_grafico = mysql_query("SELECT artigo_visual FROM  artigo order by artigo_visual desc ");
$lin_total_grafico = mysql_fetch_array($seleciona_total_grafico);

?>


<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>


    </head>
    <body>

    <?

    while($lin_artigo = mysql_fetch_array($seleciona_artigos)){

    $total_largura = ($lin_artigo ['artigo_visual']/$lin_total_grafico['artigo_visual'])*100;

    echo"<div style='width:40px;background:#ccc;'>

    <div style='background:#ccc;width:".$total_largura.";margin:5px 0;heigth:40px;display:table;line-heigth:30px;position:relative;'>

    <div style='position:absolute;width:400px;padding:5px;'>".$lin_artigo['artigo_titulo']." - ".$lin_artigo['artigo_visual']." visiatas

    <div style='display:table;float:right;padding:0 10px 0 0;'>".round($total_largura )."%</div>
</div>  
</div>  ";


    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Há quem acha que os usuários do StackOverflow têm poderes mágicos telepáticos de clarividência. Acreditam que esses seres StackOverflownianos dotados de superpoderes podem adivinhar qual é o código, a mensagem de erro  e todas as outras informações necessárias sem precisar ver nada sobre isso e ainda são capazes de descobrir o que há de errado nisso tudo. Dessa forma, esses usuários acreditam que não é necessário colocar essas informações no texto da pergunta pois elas podem ser obtidas por quem responde através de meios sobrenaturais e paranormais.

Comment: Bem-vindo, alguns posts que vc deve ler para obter sucesso nas suas perguntas  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve e mais esse  https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 0):

Rodei seu código e não apareceu erro, essa sua linha `".$lin_artigo['artigo_titulo']." - ".$lin_artigo['artigo_visual']."` me parece ser uma concatenação quando me parece q deveria ser uma subtração porque se refere a algo `visitadas`

de qq forma veja se esse dá o que vc pretende

```
<?php
include"conexao.php"; 
$seleciona_total_grafico = mysql_query('SELECT SUM(artigo_visual) AS value_sum FROM artigo'); 
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($seleciona_total_grafico); 
$sum = $row['value_sum'];

$seleciona_artigos = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM artigo order by artigo_visual desc " );

?>


<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>


    </head>
    <body>

<?php

    while($lin_artigo = mysql_fetch_array($seleciona_artigos)){

    $total_largura = ($lin_artigo ['artigo_visual']/$sum)*100;

    echo"<div style='width:40px;background:#ccc;'>

    <div style='background:#ccc;width:".$total_largura.";margin:5px 0;heigth:40px;display:table;line-heigth:30px;position:relative;'>

    <div style='position:absolute;width:400px;padding:5px;'>".$lin_artigo['artigo_titulo'] - $lin_artigo['artigo_visual']." visitadas

    <div style='display:table;float:right;padding:0 10px 0 0;'>".round($total_largura )."%</div>
</div>  
</div>  ";


    }

?>
```